# PHP utf8 encoding and decoding

Tags: php, utf-8, decode, encode

I have the following code in php

```
$test = "\151\163\142\156";
echo utf8_decode($test);
var_dump($test);
```

and i get the following result:

```
isbn
string(4) "isbn"
```

I get some text from a txt file that has the \151\163\142\156 text

```
$all_text = file_get_contents('test.txt');
var_dump($all_text);
```

result:

```
string(16) "\151\163\142\156"
```

I have the following questions:

1. how can i utf8 decode the second text so i get the isbn result?
2. how can i encode the isbn to get \151\163\142\156 ?

**EDIT**

*(from comments)*

I tried everything with iconv and encode but nothing worked. The text from the .txt file is string(16) and not string(4) so i can encode it. The txt file is saved from sublime with Western (ISO 8859-1) encoding

Comment: Seriously? `utf8_decode($all_text);`? `utf8_encode('WHAT YOU NEED')`?

Comment: that does not work. I get the same text and not the encoded one. as you can see the first one $test is string(4) and the second is string(16)

Comment: Do you decode second string? Show output of __DECODED__ `$all_text`

Comment: `$all_text_utf8_decoded = utf8_decode(file_get_contents('test.txt'));` and http://php.net/manual/de/function.utf8-encode.php

Comment: does that matter, as `file_get_contents` is a reference point for the file rather than a container for the data itself?

Comment: I'm writing a big update to my answer so will add that in as it may be useful although I don't personally think it would cause an encoding issue, but I'm far from certain. `:-)`

Comment: haha, I have credited it to you :-) I'm not in a position to test the quotes just now, although reading the SO link about double and single quotes doesn't mention anything about encodings......

Comment: Just edited my answer to show how to convert chars to codes. Enjoy! (upvote if useful ^_º).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This has absolutely nothing to do with UTF-8 encoding.** Forget about that part entirely. `utf8_decode` doesn't do anything in your code. `iconv` is entirely unrelated.

It has to do with **PHP string literal interpretation**. The `\...` in  `"\151\163\142\156"` is a special PHP string literal escape sequence:

> `\[0-7]{1,3}`
> the sequence of characters matching the regular expression is a character in octal notation, which silently overflows to fit in a byte (e.g. "\400" === "\000")
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Which very easily explains why it works when written in a PHP string literal, and doesn't work when reading from an outside source (because the external text read through `file_get_contents` is not being interpreted as PHP code). Simply do `echo "\151\163\142\156"` and you'll see "isbn" without any other conversions necessary.

To manually convert the individual escape sequences in the string `\151\163\142\156` to their character equivalents (really: their byte equivalents):

```
$string = '\151\163\142\156';  // note: single quotes cause no iterpretation
echo preg_replace_callback('/\\\\([0-7]{1,3})/', function ($m) {
    return chr(octdec($m[1]));
}, $string)
// isbn
```

[`stripcslashes`](http://php.net/stripcslashes) happens to include this functionality, but it also does a whole lot of other things which may be undesired.

The other way around:

```
$string = 'isbn';
preg_replace_callback('/./', function ($m) {
    return '\\' . decoct(ord($m[0]));
}, $string)
// \151\163\142\156
```

Comment: Thank you. That's what i wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `stripcslashes` :

```
<?php

$test = "\151\163\142\156";
echo utf8_decode( $test );                         // "isbn"
var_dump( $test );

echo "<br/><br/><br/>";

$all_text = file_get_contents( "test.txt" );
echo utf8_decode( $all_text ) .                    // "\151\163\142\156"
     "<br/>" .
     utf8_decode( stripcslashes( $all_text ) );    // "isbn"
var_dump( stripcslashes( $all_text ) );

?>
```

Tested with this file :

> This is some text :
>
> \151\163\142\156
>
> And this is more text!!!

Next is how to convert chars to codes :

```
<?php
$test = "isbn";
$coded = "";
for ( $i = 0; $i < strlen( $test ); $i++ ) // PROCESS EACH CHAR IN STRING.
  $coded .= "\\" . decoct( ord( $test[ $i ] ) ); // CHAR CODE TO OCTAL.

echo $coded .                           // "\151\163\142\156"
     "<br/>" .
     stripcslashes( $coded );           // "isbn".
?>
```

Let's make it more general with a function that we can call anywhere :

```
<?php
function code_string ( $s )
{ $coded = "";
  for ( $i = 0; $i < strlen( $s ); $i++ )
    $coded .= "\\" . decoct( ord( $s[ $i ] ) );
  return $coded;
}

$x = code_string( "isbn" );
echo $x .                           // "\151\163\142\156"
     "<br/>" .
     stripcslashes( $x );           // "isbn".
?>
```

Comment: You can get rid of `utf8_decode` entirely, it doesn't do anything here.

Comment: @deceze, I agree, but the OP seems to like it (it's possible that the text file will come with weird characters).

Comment: I thought you were trying to educate the OP about what they're doing wrong and/or are misunderstanding...!? :-P

Comment: Thank you guys. Both yours and @deceze was a great solution.